# PHP newer version fails decoding json "version like" string (ex: "0.7.4"->"0.7")

Tags: php, json

Executing this code in PHP I expect the string `"0.7.4"` remaining as `"0.7.4"` https://3v4l.org/gX4vM

```
$value = "0.7.4";

if(!empty($value))
{
  $jsonValue = json_decode($value);
  if(!empty($jsonValue)) $value = $jsonValue;
}

print_r( $value,false);
```

And this is true for almost every PHP version but in my AWS with PHP 5.6.9, and in this php sandbox (5.6.4 ?), I'm getting `0.7`  http://ideone.com/2uuoHw

In my code `$value` can be a deserializable string or a simple string ("['a','b']", "{'a':'10'}", "abc", "2500", etc.) and I expect the json to decode it properly. But I have no idea how to avoid this strange issue.

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Wait.. `0.7.4` is a valid json encoded string for php?

Comment: @Federico: PHP can encode/decode scalar values (see: http://php.net/json_decode).

Comment: @Rocket How is `0.7.4` a scalar value?

Comment: @deceze: It's not... you're right.  It'd have to be `$value = '"0.7.4"';` to be.

Comment: @Federico It use to be in all older versions. Not strict json, but ignored at least by json, not modified with unexpected criteria. Looks like trying to decode "0.7.4" as a float ignoring the second dot. Strange decision.

Comment: I'd say that it's strange you didn't get a FALSE for result. How would you even use `0.7.4` after decoding in JS? The data you posted isn't valid JSON.

Comment: @Mjh: it does: https://3v4l.org/aQ0Ip (error => NULL value)

Comment: @Mjh I would be glad with a false or a null, but not with a random decode.

Comment: same here: http://ideone.com/2uuoHw  (0.7.4 is not float(0.7), it should be error or null)

Comment: On PHP `5.6.10`, when I run the exact same code as posted in the question, I get `0.7.4` back. However, `json_last_error_msg()` correctly reports `Syntax Error`. Can you verify on your version by calling `json_last_error_msg()`?

Comment: @Mjh Ok, I have the error now, but not the null to detect that something went wrong. Don't you think that NULL is the expected result?

Comment: You are correct, it's inconsistent and null would be expected always in case of an error. As for why it is - well, human error or something else probably plays the part. However, I always use the verification in the form of `if(json_last_error() === JSON_ERROR_NONE)` before proceeding to work with the result.

Comment: Not lucky: http://ideone.com/hfXBxb  error 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated, `0.7.4` is not valid JSON (according to the JSON spec), but PHP's `json_decode` *can* decode *scalar values*, too.

> PHP implements a superset of JSON as specified in the original » RFC 4627 - it will also encode and decode scalar types and NULL. RFC 4627 only supports these values when they are nested inside an array or an object.

<sub>From: http://php.net/json_decode</sub>

If you had `$value ='"0.7.4"';` (7 characters), then `json_decode()` would decode this to the *string* `0.7.4`.  But since your *value* is `0.7.4` (5 characters, since it's missing the double quotes), it can't be decoded.

Your example at https://3v4l.org/gX4vM is *failing* to decode `$value` and just printing out its *original* value (see: https://3v4l.org/e3um2).

EDIT: For some *weird* reason, the example at http://ideone.com/2uuoHw is decoding `0.7.4` as the *float* `0.7`.  That shouldn't happen.  You should only get `0.7` if you stated with `$value = "0.7":` (see: https://3v4l.org/H2W5M).

Comment: The problem is I'm having this behaviour in my Amazon elastic-beanstalk instance... And I need a workaround.

Comment: @MarioM.: What if you check if your `$value` starts with a `[` or `{`?  And ignore trying to decode scalar values.  If you *really* need to decode scalars, maybe you can use a regex to see if it starts with a `"` (or contains only *one* `.`)?

Answer (score 2):

0.7.4 is not valid JSON.
This is valid JSON {"data": "0.7.4"}
Learn more about JSON here [json.org](http://www.json.org/)

JSON to Object:

```
$json = '{"data": "0.7.4"}';
$obj = json_decode($json);
var_dump($obj);
```

JSON to Array:

```
$json = '{"data": "0.7.4"}';
$array = json_decode($json, true);
var_dump($array);
```

Comment: I understand it's not a valid value, because of that I expect an error and a null from json_decode but in some php versions I get float(0.7) and `echo (json_last_error() === JSON_ERROR_NONE) //true`  http://ideone.com/hfXBxb

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. Don't check if the result is `empty()`, check if the result is NULL.  [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode) returns NULL if the input could not be decoded.
2. The input string `0.7.4` is invalid JSON.  **Period.**  It worked [at one point](https://3v4l.org/Bq1Pd) in PHP, but it was a [mistake](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=38680) that it worked at all.  You should not depend on this behavior as it is incorrect.

The modified version of your code should probably look like:

```
$value = "0.7.4";

if( !empty($value) )
{
    $jsonValue = json_decode($value);
    if ( $jsonValue !== NULL ) {
        // Pick a value to return
        $value = $jsonValue->something;

    } else {
        // Do nothing, leave $value as is
    }
}

var_dump($value);
```